# Question on Bracket Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation

Is it valid to say that that if $A$ is an operator then:

$$\langle f|A|g\rangle=\langle f|g\rangle A~?$$

Comment: No. How should it? The left-hand side is a complex number whereas the right-hand side is still an operator...

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not. You can see an immediate problem by asking yourself "what type of quantities do I have on each side":

- $\langle f |A| g \rangle$ is a complex scalar. indeed, an operator applied to a vector such as $A|g\rangle$ is a vector we'll call $|h\rangle$, thus the scalar product of the two vectors  $\langle f|A| g \rangle =\langle f|h\rangle$ gives a scalar
- $\langle f|g\rangle$ is also a scalar, so $\langle f|g\rangle A$ is just an operator scaled by a scalar

It doesn't make sense in any way to have a scalar equal to an operator, so that's definitely a no. $A|g\rangle \neq |g\rangle A$ any day of the week

If you're in doubt as to a notation, just go back to its definition.

If  $\langle f |A| g \rangle$ is just a neat way to write $\int f^*(x)Ag(x)dx$, is it now easier for you to see how it differs from $(\int f^*(x)g(x)dx) A$ ? In general, be careful to switch stuff around in a non-commutative algebra (even if here the problem is more basic than a commutation issue)